# how to display and download file in front-end which is pulled from back-end in an odata string in sap ui5

Tags: sapui5

In SAP UI5, I am trying to display files of any format(pdf, word, jpg) in front-end which are pulled from the back-end using odata.
In front-end, I have displayed the data in a table- Fields (File name , extension, size, Attachement link).
What i want to achieve, when user clicks on attachment link, the file of the specified format should be created and displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [sap.ui.core.util.File](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.util.File) **save** method. Working example below.

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/util/File"])
 sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
   "use strict";
   sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
     onInit: function() {
     
     }
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({
     viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
    }).placeAt("content");
   });
   
 doDownload = function(oEvent) {
   sap.ui.core.util.File.save("csv content", "myfile", "csv", "text/csv");
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>SAPUI5</title>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout">

    <layout:MatrixLayout>
     <layout:rows>
       <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
         <layout:MatrixLayoutCell padding="None">

                <Button text="Download CSV" press="doDownload" />

         </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
      </layout:rows>
    </layout:MatrixLayout>


  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

NOTE: I answer [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659402/displaying-csv-file-from-server-in-sapui5) before. I copy/past my answer here. Because I cannot flag this question as duplicated with old one.